# <xsl:apply-templates> with <xsl:sort> and <xsl:with-param> - can't select correct value from XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML file with the following simplified structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<application>
  <people>
    <entry name="abc" translator="true" languages="de, en" />
    <entry name="def" translator="true" languages="ar" />
    <entry name="ghi" translator="true" languages="ru" />
  </people>
</application>
```

The XSL is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="/application">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>Translators</h2>
        <xsl:call-template name="translators" />
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="entry">
    <xsl:param name="comment" />

    <xsl:value-of select="@name" />

    <xsl:if test="string-length($comment) > 0">
      <xsl:text> (</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$comment" />
      <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()"><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">, &lt;br /></xsl:text></xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="translators">
    <p>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/application/people/entry[@translator='true']">
        <xsl:sort data-type="text" order="ascending" case-order="upper-first" select="@name" />
        <xsl:with-param name="comment" select="@languages" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to output the translators line by line to an HTML page and add the languages they understand as comment after their name. However, my xsl:with-param seems to be ignored. I already tried other selections but how can I access the sorted entries and ensure the template is called with the correct data as parameter?

I also changed the code to use xsl:for-each but ended by getting single calls to the entry template (then the commas and br tags are missing). I'm using the entry template for outputting other people like authors and other contributers too and don't want to change it (if possible).

```
      <xsl:for-each select="/application/people/entry[@translator='true']">
        <xsl:sort data-type="text" order="ascending" case-order="upper-first" select="@name" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
          <xsl:with-param name="comment" select="@languages" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:for-each>
```

Is there a better approach to reach the goal? Is it possible to extract the @languages attribute and add it as parameter to the entry template? Do you know another way? Thank you.

Comment: If you match on `entry` and simply want to access the `languages` attribute of the matched element, why do you need the parameter at all and can't simply use `@languages` inside the template?

Comment: To make it clear, for the `xsl:with-param` https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-with-param "The focus used for computing the value specified by the xsl:with-param element is the same as that used for its parent instruction." meaning the focus is the same as the one for the `apply-templates` e.g. in your sample the `application` element while the the `xsl:sort` computes a sort key for each `entry`.

Comment: Good question. I use several templates which match translators, authors, ... and they all call the same entry template to display their data. They need different attributes in their comment fields. The parameter is only there to avoid the if statements.But you're right, I can also use one common template for all contributor categories and handle the specific stuff in the entry template. Maybe I will. I thought I made something wrong with the select attribute of the parameter and it only needs a fix there...